# How to test Rails layout templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to write tests (or more precisely, since I use RSpec, specs) for properties of a layout template.  My first idea was to write a test directly for the layout template.  However this has a few problems:

- The search path for partials changes.  Especially it includes `app/views/layouts/`, whereas rendering a concrete page doesn't include this directory.
- I can't use `url_for` inside the layout template.  It fails with the error "No route matches {:action=>"simple_page", :controller=>"layouts"}".  Of course, this can't work, as I'm not rendering a concrete page (therefore it doesn't have a URL).  A solution for this problem needs a way to inject some dummy URL.

The spec looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe "layouts/simple_page.html.haml" do
    it "contains a link to itself" do
        render
        expect(rendered).to match "^/"
    end
end
```

For the sake of a more minimal example, `app/views/layouts/simple_page.html.haml` contains only `= url_for`.

Comment: Presumably, you have at least one controller that uses this template? So you could use its actions/views to get a rendered page, against which you can make your assertions.

Comment: Me personally, I think testing views (writing tests AND maintaining them) is a meaningless waste of time. if your views contain little to no logic (as they should), there simply is nothing to test! A cursory visual inspection is enough. But I may very well be wrong about this.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev To answer your first comment: after calling `render` in a spec for a concrete view, `rendered` contains only the body for this particular page without the layout around. Even if there's a way around that, I'd like to avoid it because I want to test a property of all pages using this layout, not only of a single page.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev To answer your second comment: in this case I want to test whether the `hreflang` HTML tags are properly rendered. They are invisible in the browser, so it's important to test them.

Comment: "after calling render in a spec for a concrete view" - ah, but you could use the controller spec, I think, and inspect page content there. That one should render the full thing.

Comment: Food for thought: testing a _layout_ is useless if a controller doesn't use it. Your test will pass, but the page will be broken.